# Accessing Azure Storage Tables from C++ code

Tags: c++, azure

I have a c++ dll running on azure instance role with no problems.
I want the dll to be able to access - read and write - into an Azure Storage account. Specifically, read and write to a storage table.
Is it even possible?
Would appreciate any examples!

thanks,
Nava

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since **everything** in the Windows Azure Platform is managed through a REST Services, you just need a reliable REST library for C++ to perform what you need.

You can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961238/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-c-c-restful-framework) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222879/restful-client-api-in-c) questions for C++ REST library.

Then you can revice the [Azure Storage Services REST API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179355.aspx) for more details on what you want to achieve.

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

Just looked the the [POCO libraries](http://pocoproject.org/index.html), noted they have [HTTPRequest](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPRequest.html) and [HTTPResponse](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPResponse.html) classes. They, along with [X509Certificate](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.X509Certificate.html) should be enough to make a valid REST call to Azure management service.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you are still interested in accessing Azure storage with C++, but the Microsoft team has been working on this for the last several months. Check out the Casablanca libraries on DevLabs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/casablanca

Comment: Please check out the Microsoft Azure Storage Client Library for C++ available on GitHub and through NuGet. For more information, see this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/12/20/windows-azure-storage-client-library-for-cplusplus-preview.aspx