# How to access web api from visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Does anybody have an idea about how to get data from web api in visual c++?
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is too broad, but Microsoft C++ has a library called Casablanca, which can be used to make REST calls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RESTful Client API in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222879/restful-client-api-in-c)

Comment: REST API  aka Casablanka if you're working with purely microsoft products. libcurl, Qt WebKit (outdated), CEF (Chromium embedded network) if your code must be portable.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have a built-in library for http. You can use either one of the multitude of libraries that exist that do this, for instance [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/), or you can just use the socket API (in visual studio that would be winsock2) and write your own http request and response handling code.